# How to solve this SQL error varbinary = varchar(42)

Tags: sql, cryptocurrency, dune

I am trying to learn something new, might I know what is the error message mean?

[image]

[image]

I tried to change the code in below, then work fine. What is the difference between them?

[image]

Comment: Please don’t post images. Add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Answer (score 0):

Simply, Dune is picky about the type of the arguments you give him, then `0x40`, `64`, and `'@'` can't be compared. (Note that all these values can be compared on MySQL, but, `64=0x40`, `64='64'` and `0x40='@'` which can be weird : a single number written in different ways equals different strings).

Type strictness can be handy, since it avoids errors which can be easilly detected by the computer. I tend to prefer such languages.

Note that if you type `SELECT '\x1234'`, you have the result `\x1234`, a 6 characters string, not exactly what you would mean. This is confirmed with `select length('\x1234');` (6). The `\` is not interpreted.

Note that on MySQL, `select length ('\\')` returns 1, and on Dune returns 2. It seems `\` has not the common behaviour of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use `from_hex('0xc2132d05d31c914a87c6611c10748aeb04b58e8f')` method to convert varchar to varbinary in Dune.

**from_hex(varchar) → varbinary** :

Converts a varbinary expression in datatype string to varbinary datatype

**Example:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM ethereum.transactions tx
WHERE tx."from" = from_heb('0xc2132d05d31c914a87c6611c10748aeb04b58e8f')
```

*For more info read the official doc:*

https://dune.com/docs/query/DuneSQL-reference/Functions-and-operators/varbinary/#from_utf8